# Why does tsql Rand function not work in where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random

I am trying to select a single row at random from a table.   I am curious as to why the two statements below don't work:

```
select LastName from DataGeneratorNameLast where id = (ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 3)+1

select LastName from DataGeneratorNameLast where id = cast(Ceiling(RAND(convert(varbinary, newid())) *4) as int)
```

Both statements return, at random, either 1 row, no rows, or multiple rows.  For the life of me I can't figure out why.   Just adding top 1 to the query only solves the problem of multiple rows - but not of no rows returned.

Yes I could do the same thing by selecting top 1 and ordering by newid().  But the mystery of why this does not work is driving me crazy.

Thoughts on why I get multiple rows back?

Here is the table I am using to select from:

```
Create Table dbo.DataGeneratorNameLast
(
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
)
Go

insert into DataGeneratorNameLast (LastName) values ('SMITH')
insert into DataGeneratorNameLast (LastName) values ('JOHNSON')
insert into DataGeneratorNameLast (LastName) values ('Booger')
insert into DataGeneratorNameLast (LastName) values ('Tiger')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `newid()` gets evaluated for every row it is compared against, generating a different number. To do what you want, you should generate the random value into a variable before the select and then reference the variable.

```
Declare @randId int = (abs(checksum(newid())) % 3) + 1;

select LastName from DataGeneratorNameLast where id = @randId;
```

As Martin said in comments to this. Rand() would behave differently, only being evaluated once per query.

Comment: True but only because of the `newid` seed. `rand()` on its own would be [evaluated once](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/wrapping-my-head-around-rand-in-sql-server/).

Comment: @MartinSmith I've tried it out, and can see empirically that you are right. But I can't see anything in the documentation to understand why. If you'd care to write a different answer, I'll remove mine.

Comment: It is because `rand` is treated as a "runtime constant" but `newid` isn't.

Comment: Hi.  I don't want to assign it to a variable.  I want to use this statement as a sub query to insert lots of test/fake customer data with random names.

Comment: Hi.  I still can't figure out how/why a select statement that has "id = [MyRandomValue] could possibly return more than 1 row, where id is a unique set incrimenting integers.  It seems like a defect to me.  Thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If the table has at least one row that this query would return one row is mandatory.

```
select TOP (1) LastName 
from DataGeneratorNameLast 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Notice that this solution can be slow if the table has a large number of rows.

About `select LastName from DataGeneratorNameLast where id = @Rand` - This solution does not guarantee that there exists a row with id. Even the IDENTITY column can contain gaps. If you definitely need one row then do a preliminary check `IF EXISTS (select * from DataGeneratorNameLast where id = @Rand) SELECT ...`

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the answer.  Yes, I have seen that solution.  I am not concerned about gaps in the identity column.  What I can't figure out how/why a select statement that has "id = [MyRandomValue] could possibly return more than 1 row, where id is a unique set incrimenting integers.  It seems like a defect to me.  Thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I've Had a similar issue and fixed it by making the ID a PRIMARY KEY.

NEWID() is computed per-row. Without a primary key, there is no access pattern other than a table scan, and the filter is checked for each row, so a different value is computed for each row, and you get however many rows match.

With the key, a seek is available, so the predicate is computed once and used as a search argument for a seek.